# Customer needs to login every 15 minutes

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm facing a problem with login.

The customer needs to login every 15 minutes.

I changed the Default Cookie Settings

Cookie Lifetime to 10368000

And I changed the Persistent Shopping Cart --->
Persistence Lifetime (seconds) to 31536000

And still, keeps logout every 15 minutes.

Magento version 2.4.2

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should go to:

Stores > configurations > Customer > Customer Configuration > Online Customer Options, and set the online minutes interval as per your wish.

[image]

Don't forget to set the store view.